# Is it possible to create sound editors in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, audio

I want to make an app with editing sound in Flutter(select a range and cut, etc). So I've been searching for  packages or plugin related with this function, but its' hard to find. I already found an audio player plugin, but I'm not sure whether there are packages for editing sound or not. Please let me know how to handle it. I will really appreciate it if you give me a example code.

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at the [ffmpeg plugin for flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter), ffmpeg is a command line solution to edit audio and video, and you can integrate it with flutter. Take a look at their [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/) and test the possibilities with their filters